# A Php server using sockets or connect to the database

Tags: php, sockets

Connecting to the database at each request can be expensive the solution to that could be using memcached. However i have been working on a php socket server that will be available in the background to fetch data from. This way on my php server i can fetch all the data i need and on the web request connect to it and retrieve the data without having to go through the data base.

I couldn't find any data on this so my question is how expensive is it to connect to my php server using sockets. Is there a down side to it?

Note: The php socket server is running on the same machine and will be able to serve multiple applications.